# Order BY is not supported in view in sql server

Tags: sql-server

i am trying to create a view in sql server.

```
create view distinct_product as
select distinct name from stg_user_dtlprod_allignmnt_vw order by name;
```

this is showing an error.

error message is:

> The ORDER BY clause is invalid in views, inline functions, derived tables, subqueries, and common table expressions, unless TOP or FOR XML is also specified.

plz help me out where i am wrong.

Comment: The message is self-explanatory: you cannot use `order by` in a view.

Comment: You can do `select * from YourView ORDER BY SomeField` afterwards though.

Comment: You could create a stored procedure that will order the data as you require.

Answer (score 4):

You *could* use `TOP` with a number that is greater than the number of records:

```
CREATE VIEW [dbo].[distinct_product]
AS
SELECT DISTINCT TOP 10000000 name
FROM  stg_user_dtlprod_allignmnt_vw 
ORDER BY name
```

You cannot use `TOP 100 PERCENT` since the  optimizer recognizes that TOP 100 PERCENT qualifies all rows and does not need to be computed at all, so the  ORDER BY wouldn't be guaranteed.

Comment: Yeah. And slow everything down with the distinct.

Comment: @TomTom: OP wants to use distinct, it wasn't my idea.

Answer (score 3):

You can't order a view like that when it's created as the message states, unless you follow the other answers from Tim / Raphael, but you can order results selected from a view:

So create it in step 1:

```
create view distinct_product as
    select distinct name 
    from stg_user_dtlprod_allignmnt_vw
```

Then order it when you retrieve data:

```
select * 
from distinct_product 
order by name
```

Comment: It's not so simple if you want to show that view for example in a client app like MS-Excel. Then i like to apply the order-by in the view directly.

Comment: @TimSchmelter perhaps, but the OP hasn't specified how the data is going to be used

Answer (score 3):

A view cannot be sorted with an **ORDER BY** clause. You need to put the **ORDER BY** clause into any query that references the view.

A view is not materialized - the data isn't stored, so how could it be sorted? A view is kind of like a stored procedure that just contains a SELECT with no parameters... it doesn't hold data, it just holds the definition of the query. Since different references to the view could need data sorted in different ways, the way that you do this - just like selecting from a table, which is also an unsorted collection of rows, by definition - is to include the order by on the outer query.